# Does having a ccTLD mean your domains is less likely to show up in other countries?

Tags: domains

The .com is unavailable, so I'm considering purchasing the ccTLD for my new company. That said, at some point I'll probably wish to sell the product internationally (even if just online), so I'm wondering what, if any, effect the ccTLD would have on my website's rankings in other countries' search engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an effect of load-balancing and data center loading that Google (at least) applies using in part the TLD/gTLD/ccTLD and of course language. The ccTLDs are placed into the search engines that Google runs based primarily upon search history and language. Any .com site is subject to this effect too, however, .com sites especially English sites, enjoy a greater foot print in Googles various search engines overall. Having said that, some ccTLDs enjoy a very large foot print as well such as .de, .uk, .us, and so on. Today, language seems to be the dominant factor followed by search history- who search searches for what and the click-through rate of sites including examining the TLD/gTLD/ccTLD.

Comment: So in conclusion? :)

Comment: @zakgottlieb It would all depend upon the ccTLD. You are in the UK and if you are talking about a .uk domain, you should be okay, but do not expect to show up in every country. An obvious example, would be that a .uk domain will not likely show up in .vn Vietnam. Think language first and then likelihood that domain would be of value to a particular region. For example, .uk and .fr. It is likely that someone in France would be interested in a content from a .uk domain.